# интеграция django + 1c

Tags: python, django, 1с

Всем привет! Есть интернет магазин на django. Кто может подсказать как интегрировать 1с и django? Чтобы категории и товары на автомате выгружались и создавались в django и потом из django прилетал заказ в 1с вместе с данными клиента. Приветствуется любая помошь:D. Наткнулся на такую статью, как по мне это слишком https://habr.com/ru/post/139272/
Как я понял из всех документаций, каким-то образом нужно сформировать в 1с выгрузку двух файлов товары.xml и заказы.xml по ftp и гонять их туда - сюда через интервал который прописывается в разделе 1с "интеграция с сайтом"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В 1С не шарю,но шарю в Django.

1. Чтобы загружать данные из БД, можешь использовать [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#loaddata)
2. Чтобы выгружать данные в БД Django, можно использовать [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)
3. Чтобы из Django прилетал заказ на 1C можно использовать какую нибудь API или FTP интеграцию с ним, через [сигналы](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch). Например заказ через форму создается, сигнал это "отлавливает" и делает выгрузку на 1С

- вот тебе пост с habr https://habr.com/ru/post/462453/ 2015 год, вроде не сложно
- А тут обсуждают твою проблему https://qna.habr.com/q/62836

Comment: Спасибо большое, бро!